# Median survival time in individual models separated by a variable vs a single model with covariate

Tags: survival, median

Suppose I wish to find the median survival time of each sex in `lung` data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

test_pool <- survfit(
  Surv(time, status) ~ sex,
  data = lung,
  error = "greenwood",
  type = "kaplan-meier",
  conf.type = "log-log",
  conf.int = 0.95
) %>%
  summary() %>%
  .$table


test_1 <- survfit(
  Surv(time, status) ~ 1,
  data = lung %>% filter(sex == 1),
  error = "greenwood",
  type = "kaplan-meier",
  conf.type = "log-log",
  conf.int = 0.95
) %>%
  summary() %>%
  .$table

test_2 <- survfit(
  Surv(time, status) ~ 1,
  data = lung %>% filter(sex == 2),
  error = "greenwood",
  type = "kaplan-meier",
  conf.type = "log-log",
  conf.int = 0.95
) %>%
  summary() %>%
  .$table
```

which returns:

```
> test_pool
      records n.max n.start events    rmean se(rmean) median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
sex=1     138   138     138    112 326.0841  22.91156    270     210     306
sex=2      90    90      90     53 460.6473  34.68985    426     345     524
> test_1
  records     n.max   n.start    events     rmean se(rmean)    median   0.95LCL   0.95UCL 
138.00000 138.00000 138.00000 112.00000 326.08411  22.91156 270.00000 210.00000 306.00000 
> test_2
  records     n.max   n.start    events     rmean se(rmean)    median   0.95LCL   0.95UCL 
 90.00000  90.00000  90.00000  53.00000 455.90409  32.91742 426.00000 345.00000 524.00000
```

while the restricted survival mean time is different in `test_pool` and `test_2`, median survival time remains the same.

Since median survival time is descriptive, I assume it is not affected by a model statement, but to be sure, is it *mathematically* safe to say that the median survival time would be equivalent between the individual models separated by a sex (`test_1` and `test_2`) vs a single model with sex as covariate (`test_pool`)?